# Check if two dates are one month apart

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

I'm trying to check if two dates are 1 month apart. I read that I should use this method `components:fromDate:toDate:options:` from `NSCalendar`

My code

```
#define FORMAT_DATE_TIME @"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"

NSDate *updateDate = [Utils getDateFromString:airport.updateOn withFormat:FORMAT_DATE_TIME];
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSString *nowString = [Utils getStringFromDate:now withFormat:FORMAT_DATE_TIME];
now = [Utils getDateFromString:nowString withFormat:FORMAT_DATE_TIME];

NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSDateComponents *comps = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitMonth fromDate:updateDate toDate:now options:0];

NSLog(@"%ld", (long)[comps year]);
NSLog(@"%ld", (long)[comps month]);
NSLog(@"%ld", (long)[comps day]);
```

These are the logs:

> (lldb) Year: 9223372036854775807
>
> (lldb) Month: 0
>
> (lldb) Day: 9223372036854775807
>
> (lldb) po now 2017-08-23 11:54:00 +0000
>
> (lldb) po updateDate 2017-08-23 11:48:00 +0000

Shouldn't all the value be zero?

Comment: I think it's the default "unset" value (equivalent to 2^63-1). If you print `NSDateComponents` is may not print the year and day because you didn't ask for it in `components:fromDate:toDate:options:`.

Comment: You don't need to convert the date to and from a string.

Comment: No, they shouldn't. It's just uninitialized variables, values in them are unpredictable and shouldn't be referred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below line does not include the Year (`NSCalendarUnitYear`) and Day (`NSCalendarUnitDay`) component, only Month (`NSCalendarUnitMonth`) component is included.

```
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitMonth fromDate:updateDate toDate:now options:0];
```

Add `NSCalendarUnitYear` and `NSCalendarUnitDay` to get [comps year] & [comps day] as 0.

Like this :

```
NSDateComponents * components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitMonth |NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:updateDate toDate:now options:0];
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use this

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:FORMAT_DATE_TIME];
NSDate *updateDate  = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"24-07-1990 15:20"];

NSDate *now = [NSDate date];


NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];

unsigned unitFlags = NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth |  NSCalendarUnitDay;


NSDateComponents *comps = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:updateDate toDate:now options:0];


NSLog(@"%ld", (long)[comps year]);
NSLog(@"%ld", (long)[comps month]);
NSLog(@"%ld", (long)[comps day]);
```

Comment: @bruno check again i was not read your Question good at first time